# Check for sequence of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table from a ticketing system, that is formatted something like this (only rows for two sample tickets shown):

```
-----------------------------------------
| commentid |  ticketid  | ticketstatus |
|-----------|------------|--------------|
|    105    |    1337    |      TBQ     |
|    109    |    4242    |      TBP     |
|    118    |    1337    |      TBQ     |
|    121    |    4242    |    closed    |
|    125    |    1337    |   finished   | 
|    176    |    1337    |    closed    |
-----------------------------------------
```

Where `ticketid` is the unique ID of a ticket,  `commentid` the index which is incremented for every new comment and `ticketstatus` is the status of the ticket.

Now, I would like to count the number of tickets, where the status changed directly from *TBQ* to *finished* or directly from *TBQ* to *closed*.

I think this should be possible with a recursive CTE, but stuff gets more complicated because `commentid` is not a direct sequence for one ticket but rather for all tickets. Additionally, there can be quite a number of rows between status changes of a single ticket.

The query should return "1" for the example table above, since ticket 1337 is the only ticket that changes state directly from *TBQ* to *closed*

How would I do this?

Comment: please post output also unable to understand question

Comment: Are there any rules how those status changes might occur? E.g. multiple *TBQ*/*TBP* followed by a single *closed*  or *finished*?

Comment: 1337 changes from TBQ to TBQ. Isn't that a problem?

Comment: @SalmanA a comment does not have to change the ticket status

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you really want is `lag()`, but that is not available in SQL Server 2008.  You can use `apply` instead:

```
select c.*, cprev.*
from comments c cross apply
     (select top 1 cprev.*
      from comments cprev
      where cprev.ticketid = c.ticketid and
            cprev.commentid < c.commentid
      order by cprev.commentid desc
     ) cprev
where cprev.ticketstatus = 'TBQ' and
      c.ticketstatus in ('finished', 'closed');
```

If you want a count of such tickets then use `select count(*)` or `select count(distinct c.ticketid)` (if this can happen more than one time for a given ticket).